# Highlight the middle row in a scrolling table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking to create a scrolling table, where say, 10 rows are viewable when scrolling at any time, but with the middle row always highlighted, even when scrolling.

The idea being that as the user scrolls down, the class of middle row changes incrementally as they scroll.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLqbto3v/)

I have created a basic table where the middle row is highlighted, but when I start scrolling I want the highlighted class to move to the next row, giving the effect that the middle row always appears highlighted in the middle.

```css
table {
 max-width: 980px;
 table-layout: fixed;
 margin: auto;
}

th, td {
 padding: 5px 10px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}

thead, tfoot {
 background: #f9f9f9;
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 width: calc(100% - 18px);
}

tbody {
 height: 300px;
 overflow: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}

tbody tr {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 table-layout: fixed;
}

.highlighted{
 background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<body>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Header 1</th>
      <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
      <th scope="col">Header 3</th>
      <th scope="col">Header 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class= "highlighted" >Cell content</td>
      <td class= "highlighted" >Cell content</td>
      <td class= "highlighted" >Cell content</td>
      <td class= "highlighted" >Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Footer 1</td>
      <td>Footer 2</td>
      <td>Footer 3</td>
      <td>Footer 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `nth-child`

```
tbody tr:nth-child(5n) td{
 background-color: coral;
}
```

```css
table {
 max-width: 980px;
 table-layout: fixed;
 margin: auto;
}

th, td {
 padding: 5px 10px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}

thead, tfoot {
 background: #f9f9f9;
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 width: calc(100% - 18px);
}

tbody {
 height: 300px;
 overflow: auto;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}

tbody tr {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 table-layout: fixed;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(5n) td{
 background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<body>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Header 1</th>
      <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
      <th scope="col">Header 3</th>
      <th scope="col">Header 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class= "highlighted" >Cell content</td>
      <td class= "highlighted" >Cell content</td>
      <td class= "highlighted" >Cell content</td>
      <td class= "highlighted" >Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
      <td>Cell content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Footer 1</td>
      <td>Footer 2</td>
      <td>Footer 3</td>
      <td>Footer 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for, this makes every 5th row highlighted. As I scroll I want the next row on to be highlighted. So that the bottom row within the tables viewport is highlighted as I scroll, moving on to the next roll as I scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider a background on the table element that will remain fixed:

```css
table {
  max-width: 980px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: auto;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

thead,
tfoot {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 18px);
}

tbody {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(coral,coral) 
    3px calc(50% + 3px) /*left top*/
    /
    calc(100% - 22px) 30px  /* Width height*/
    no-repeat;
}

tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

/*.highlighted {
  background-color: coral;
}*/
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Header 1</th>
        <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
        <th scope="col">Header 3</th>
        <th scope="col">Header 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="highlighted">Cell content</td>
        <td class="highlighted">Cell content</td>
        <td class="highlighted">Cell content</td>
        <td class="highlighted">Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>Footer 1</td>
        <td>Footer 2</td>
        <td>Footer 3</td>
        <td>Footer 4</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Nice idea, but ideally I need to a attach class to the next row as I scroll as it's not just a highlight effect that I need to apply to it.

Answer (score 0):

So first we need to define our table and cell height( I assumed all cell height size are same ), as well as cell size in one view so we can use it later to find cell in the half of view.

```
    var $table = $("#table");
    var $scrollableBody = $("#tbody");
    var $scrollableBodyRow = $("#tbody > tr");
    var scrollableHeight = $scrollableBody.height();
    var cellHeight = $scrollableBody.find('tr').height();
    var cellsInView = Math.round(scrollableHeight / cellHeight);
```

So now we know how much rows are in on viewport - cellsInView.

Now we need to create function that will return top row per scroll, top cell is equal to scroll top position divided by cell height. After we know that we just have to add half of items per view from starting cell.

```
 var findMiddle = function () {
      var offsetTop = $scrollableBody.scrollTop(),
        index;

      if (offsetTop === 0) {
        // find middle one
        index = Math.round(cellsInView / 2) - 1;
      } else {
        var topCell = Math.round(offsetTop / cellHeight);
        $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
        index = Math.round((topCell + cellsInView / 2)) - 1
      }

      $("#row-" + index).addClass("highlighted");
    }
```

I use this as helper to toggle class.

```
    $scrollableBodyRow.each(function (index) {
      $(this).attr('id', "row-" + index);
    });
```

We set hightlight on load.

```
    findMiddle();
```

Demo link: https://jsfiddle.net/sabo9n8L/2/

Comment: @RyanPaul-HenrySainsbury  is this ok ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to change the color while scrolling you might want to use javascript too :

```js
$(function() {
  $("tbody").scroll(function(e) {
    var fifth = null;
    $("tbody tr").each(function() {
      if (isScrolledIntoView($(this)) && !fifth) {
        fifth = $(this).nextAll().eq(4);
        $(this).siblings().children("td").removeClass("highlighted");
        fifth.children("td").addClass("highlighted");
      }
    });
  });

  function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  max-width: 980px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: auto;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

thead,
tfoot {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 18px);
}

tbody {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.highlighted {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body style="-ms-zoom: 0.75;
        -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
        -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -o-transform: scale(0.75);
        -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Header 1</th>
        <th scope="col">Header 2</th>
        <th scope="col">Header 3</th>
        <th scope="col">Header 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="highlighted">Cell content</td>
        <td class="highlighted">Cell content</td>
        <td class="highlighted">Cell content</td>
        <td class="highlighted">Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
        <td>Cell content</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>Footer 1</td>
        <td>Footer 2</td>
        <td>Footer 3</td>
        <td>Footer 4</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: @RyanPaul-HenrySainsbury does this answer your question?